# Change arrow function into list of components

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to make and outlined div with label and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036265/5722505) answer, which has exactly what I was looking for. However there is a problem when I try to use some inputs inside `OutlinedDiv`. After typing any character it loses focus. I found that the problem is an arrow function used in `OutlinedDiv`:

```
inputComponent: ({ className }) => (
      <div key="divKey" className={className}>{children}</div>)
```

and if I use a simple `div` instead of `OutlinedDiv` everything works as expected. So can I rewrite `OutlinedDiv` in a way that it will work with inputs? I don't even have a feeling what are my options here.

[image: Edit Custom Outlined Component]

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import OutlinedDiv from "./OutlinedDiv";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ inputValue: "", inputValue2: "" });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OutlinedDiv key="outlinedDivKey" label="OutlinedDivTest">
        <div>
          <TextField
            id="inputValue"
            key="inputValueKey"
            name="inputValue"
            label="Some input"
            inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: "right" } }}
            value={state.inputValue}
            onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            id="inputValue2"
            key="inputValueKey2"
            name="inputValue2"
            label="Some input2"
            inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: "right" } }}
            value={state.inputValue2}
            onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
      </OutlinedDiv>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**outlinedDiv.js**

```
import React from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const OutlinedDiv = ({ children, label }) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      label={label}
      multiline
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: ({ className }) => (
          <div key="divKey" className={className}>
            {children}
          </div>
        )
      }}
    />
  );
};
export default OutlinedDiv;
```

Comment: My best suggestion would be writing your own 'OutlinedDiv' component, without using TextField, based on TextField's 'outlined' CSS. This issue happens because you put one TextField into another. It is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated my previous answer to use the following for the `OutlinedDiv` implementation:

```
import React from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const InputComponent = ({ inputRef, ...other }) => <div {...other} />;
const OutlinedDiv = ({ children, label }) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      label={label}
      multiline
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: InputComponent
      }}
      inputProps={{ children: children }}
    />
  );
};
export default OutlinedDiv;
```

This avoids re-mounting of the input component when re-rendering occurs.

Here's a modified version of your sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-outlined-component-sv2bi

Comment: My example was too simple. I want to use this as a container for few components, let's say two inputs and a select, to give them one label describing what are they responsible for. I updated my CodeSandbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is one warning showing up, about the `inputRef` being passed to `input`. I found explanation and solution [here](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/714) and changed the declaration of `InputComponent`: `const InputComponent = props => {let {inputRef, ...others} = props;return <div {...others} />};`

Comment: @EganWolf Good catch -- I wasn't paying attention to the console. I've updated my answer accordingly.