# How can I set an static outlined div similar to Material-UI's outlined textfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want wrap some TextFields in a outlined container and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032966/how-can-i-imitate-the-look-of-the-outline-and-label-from-material-uis-outlined?answertab=votes#tab-top). This work as i want:

[image]

But when I click in an inside textfield all the texfields focused:

[image]

This is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import OutlinedDiv from "./OutlinedDiv";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OutlinedDiv label="DIV">
        <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text1" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text2" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text3" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text4" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text5" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
            <TextField label="Text6" variant="outlined" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </OutlinedDiv>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

How I can achive this style and when click in an inside component only focus the selected component?

A response with another approach and the similar solution for outlined div is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code that achieved your second image?

Comment: @tic I already updated my question

Comment: Why would you want to put a load of text fields inside another text field? Do you just want an outline?

Comment: yes, what I want is a outlined div in the way it looks in the picture

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is an approach that does not leverage `TextField` or `FormControl` and thus can be safely used to wrap other inputs. This copies some styles from [OutlinedInput](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js) and the [InputLabel styles applied when within a FormControl](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L26).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import NotchedOutline from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";

const styles = {
  root: {
    position: "relative",
    marginTop: "8px"
  },
  contentWrapper: {
    position: "relative"
  },
  content: {
    padding: "18.5px 14px"
  },
  inputLabel: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    // slight alteration to spec spacing to match visual spec result
    transform: "translate(0, 24px) scale(1)"
  },
  notchedOutline: {}
};

const LabelledOutline = ({ classes, id, label, children, className }) => {
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const labelRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const labelNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(labelRef.current);
    setLabelWidth(labelNode != null ? labelNode.offsetWidth : 0);
  }, [label]);

  return (
    <div className={clsx(className, classes.root)}>
      <InputLabel
        ref={labelRef}
        htmlFor={id}
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.inputLabel}
        shrink
      >
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <div id={id} className={classes.content}>
          {children}
          <NotchedOutline
            className={classes.notchedOutline}
            notched
            labelWidth={labelWidth}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default withStyles(styles)(LabelledOutline);
```

And below is an example using it both without customization and once with customized colors for the label, outline, and content that changes on hover.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import LabelledOutline from "./LabelledOutline";

const CustomColorLabelledOutline = withStyles({
  root: {
    "& $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "purple"
    },
    "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "orange"
    },
    "& $inputLabel": {
      color: "green"
    },
    "&:hover $inputLabel": {
      color: "blue"
    },
    "& $content": {
      color: "black"
    },
    "&:hover $content": {
      color: "purple"
    }
  },
  notchedOutline: {},
  inputLabel: {},
  content: {}
})(LabelledOutline);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LabelledOutline id="myID" label="My Label">
        My Content
      </LabelledOutline>
      <CustomColorLabelledOutline label="My Label">
        My Content with custom label and outline color
      </CustomColorLabelledOutline>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit LabelledOutline]

Comment: How can I change the color of the outline/border and the label?

Comment: @425nesp I've updated the `LabelledOutline` code slightly and added an example that customizes colors.

Answer (score 0):

And the obligatory TS version (deeply inspired by @Ryan Cogswell's version):

```
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import NotchedOutline from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline";
import { makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    position: "relative",
    marginTop: "8px",
  },
  contentWrapper: {
    position: "relative",
  },
  content: {
    // padding: "18.5px 14px",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  inputLabel: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    // slight alteration to spec spacing to match visual spec result
    transform: "translate(0, 24px) scale(1)",
  },
  notchedOutline: { borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius },
}));

interface Props {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

export default function Conftainer({ id, label, children, className }: Props): ReactElement {
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const labelRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (labelRef && labelRef.current && (labelRef.current as any).offsetWidth) {
      setLabelWidth((labelRef.current as any).offsetWidth);
    }
  }, [label]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={clsx(className, classes.root)}>
      <InputLabel
        ref={labelRef}
        htmlFor={id}
        variant="outlined"
        className={classes.inputLabel}
        shrink
      >
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
        <div id={id} className={classes.content}>
          {children}
          <NotchedOutline className={classes.notchedOutline} notched labelWidth={labelWidth} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(any edits to get rid of the `any` more than welcome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough point to post a comment on @AntonOfTheWoods answer (I signed up SO today especially for this question).

Just use `const labelRef = React.useRef<HTMLLabelElement>(null);` and you should be able to get rid of the `any`

Answer (score 0):

Below is some example code on how to make a `OutlinedDiv`, focusing solely on the label+border aspects. One limitation of this approach is the absence of label shrink functionality. Nevertheless, I'm sharing it in case it proves helpful to someone.

```
import React, { ReactNode, CSSProperties } from 'react';

type OutlinedDivProps = Readonly<{ children: ReactNode; label: string }>;
const OutlinedDiv: React.FC<OutlinedDivProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, label } = props;
  return (
    <div style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <div style={styles.header}>
        <div style={styles.headerBorderBefore}></div>
        {label && <div style={styles.headerTitle}>{label && <span>{label}</span>}</div>}
        <div style={styles.headerBorderAfter}></div>
      </div>
      <div style={styles.childrenContainer}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const borderColor = '#b2b2b2';
const styles: Readonly<Record<string, CSSProperties>> = {
  mainContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    borderLeft: `1px solid ${borderColor}`,
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${borderColor}`,
    borderRight: `1px solid ${borderColor}`,
    borderRadius: '5px',
    margin: '1em',
  },
  header: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100% !important',
  },
  headerBorderBefore: {
    borderTop: `1px solid ${borderColor}`,
    width: '1em',
    borderTopLeftRadius: '5px',
  },
  headerTitle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: '0.25em',
    width: 'fit-content',
    height: '2em',
    margin: '-1em 0.5em 0em 0.5em',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    fontSize: '1em',
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  headerBorderAfter: {
    borderTop: `1px solid ${borderColor}`,
    width: '1em',
    flexGrow: 2,
    borderTopRightRadius: '5px',
  },
  childrenContainer: {
    padding: '1em',
  },
};

export default OutlinedDiv;
```