# Is it possible to display react components in an input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material UI with React and I'm trying to build an input field that can display react components mixed with text. The reason is to be able to scan the text in the input field with a regex to find "variables". For example 'Hello, my name is $name'. I want to replace the variable with a material UI chip component.[(Link)](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/#chip)

To clarify how I want it to look like.

[image]

I have looked around for libraries and I've found that [material-ui-chip-input](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input) does something similar but it doesn't look to be customisable to solve my issue.

Is there a way to render a react component in an input field or should I rethink how I should go about doing this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd say it's feasible, but you will need to build a custom input component probably.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402130/how-can-i-set-an-static-outlined-div-similar-to-material-uis-outlined-textfield/58421725#58421725) if you are just trying to reuse the outlined-input look with custom stuff inside it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I want the value to be the same as the upper input field in the image. But to display as the lower input field. So form validation and all that stuff still works. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ZekeHernandez Yeah, I''m using Material UI textfield right now but i feels like i have to build a custom one in the end. I'd rather avoid that because it takes a lot of time and can become buggy. But I think there is no options. Thanks for confirming.