# Next JS + Material UI Warning: Prop className did not match

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I am getting this error in the console, when I am using a specific custom component that uses Material UI.

I got the component from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402130/how-can-i-set-an-static-outlined-div-similar-to-material-uis-outlined-textfield/58421725#58421725).

Here is a sandbox with the error:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-dream-nxg4e

The answers I found on the internet don't work, as most of them refer to a custom _document.tsx file configured for using Material UI with next js which I already set up.

I don't get the console error in production, but instead I get weird CSS behaviour.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Sadly not properly. I ended up finding the problematic component NotchedOutline and wrapping it in NoSsr tags from "@material-ui/core/NoSsr". This causes the outline to load after everything on a server rendered page but at least there are no CSS artifacts and errors like before