# Material-UI radio buttons with "outlined" variant

Tags: reactjs, annotations, material-ui

I could not find a way to display Radio Buttons with the "outlined" variant from [FormControl](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control/).
To create an annotation form a am using React and MaterialUI.

Example:

[image: Example]

As you can see in the image above, the radio button field does not match the others.
Simply adding `variant="outlined"` to the FormControl does not work.

I wonder if this is even possible.
WBR

Comment: Found perfectly working solution on stackoverflow
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032966/how-can-i-imitate-the-look-of-the-outline-and-label-from-material-uis-outlined).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a fieldset like this:

```
<Grid item component='fieldset' className={classes.outlined}>
   <FormLabel component="legend">Title</FormLabel>
... radio buttons ..
</Grid>
```

and then use the theme to set the colour of the text etc.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    outlined: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: theme.palette.grey[300],
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderRadius: 3
    },
  }),
);
```