# MaterialUI Rating component with TextField outlined border, typing issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am attempting to create a `Rating` component that has a border with a label that imitates the `TextField` outlined border. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032966/how-can-i-imitate-the-look-of-the-outline-and-label-from-material-uis-outlined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402130/how-can-i-set-an-static-outlined-div-similar-to-material-uis-outlined-textfield/58421725#58421725) questions that more of less covered what I want to do which means using a `TextField` `inputComponent` and `inputProps` to do it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Favorite, FavoriteBorder } from "@mui/icons-material";

import "./styles.css";

const WrappedRating = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { className, onChange, value, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Rating
        onChange={(e, value) => {
          console.log("onChange", value);

          onChange({ target: { value: String(value) } });
        }}
        value={Number(value)}
        ref={ref}
        {...rest}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <Stack component="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        value={value}
        label="Rating"
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log("onChange textField", e);
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: WrappedRating,
          inputProps: {
            max: 4,
            onChangeActive: (e, newHover) => {
              //console.log("hover", newHover);
            },
            icon: <Favorite fontSize="inherit" />,
            emptyIcon: <FavoriteBorder fontSize="inherit" />
          }
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-rating-react-js-gpn591)

The code above works, but I am trying to do the same thing with TypeScript and without using `any` or `@ts-ginore`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Rating, { RatingProps } from "@mui/material/Rating";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Favorite, FavoriteBorder } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { InputBaseComponentProps } from "@mui/material";

type WrappedRatingProps = InputBaseComponentProps & RatingProps;

const WrappedRating = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, WrappedRatingProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { className, onChange, value, ...rest } = props;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <Rating
          onChange={(e, value) => {
            const event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> = {
              ...e,
              target: {
                value: String(value)
              }
            // Type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement'.
            };
            if (onChange) {
              onChange(event);
            }
          }}
          value={Number(value)}
          ref={ref}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(-1);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState<number>(-1);

  const onSubmit = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <Stack component="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        value={value}
        label="Rating"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        InputProps={{
          inputComponent: WrappedRating,
          inputProps: {
            max: 4,
            onChangeActive: (e: React.SyntheticEvent, newHover: number) => {
              setHover(newHover);
              console.log(hover);
            },
            icon: <Favorite fontSize="inherit" />,
            emptyIcon: <FavoriteBorder fontSize="inherit" />
          }
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandBox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-ts-react-rating-hj5qqc)

I've noted there's an issue regarding the value of TextField and Rating, which makes necessary to convert the types. The issue now is getting the `onChange` to work without typing issues because the `onChange` from `TextField` and `Rating` expect different things. I attempted to create a new event but it started getting extremely messy.

Any ideas? I am aware that `any` or `@ts-ginore` would get this to work, but I wanted to know if I am missing something. It is my first time asking a question, I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the type of `value` in `onChange` is already `string` as it comes from the input event in this use case, and it should not require additional conversion by creating a new event.

Tested in forked demo: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-ts-react-rating-forked-ei32yg?file=/src/App.tsx) and it did not seem to have errors.

If there is still an issue regarding the types is not aligned, any chance there might be other causes?

```
const WrappedRating = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, WrappedRatingProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    const { className, value, ...rest } = props;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <Rating
          value={Number(value)}
          ref={ref}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As expected it was simple. Looks like I missed that `TextField` is able to infer the value type and I also didn't need to use `onChange` from the Rating component as well. Appreciate your help.